# How to use loop for multiple if coniditions

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, if-statement, python-imaging-library

`labels[(x, y)]` returns the value at `coordinate(x)` and `coordinate(y)`.
`labels[(x, y)]` is actually representing a different shape in the image and after detection each shape is being saved as a different image. For every shape or component I am using multiple `if` conditions for example `if labels[(x, y)] == 0: # save it as an image`. For every new shape however I have to create a new `if`, so far i have used `7 if conditions`. How can I solve this problem with only one if condition.

```
for (x, y) in labels:
    component = uf.find(labels[(x, y)])
    labels[(x, y)] = component
    print (format(x) +","+ format(y)+ " " +format(labels[(x, y)]))

    if labels[(x, y)]==0:
        Zero[y][x]=int(255)
        count=count+1
        if count<=43:
            continue
        elif count>43:
            Zeroth = Image.fromarray(Zero)
            Zeroth.save(os.path.join(dirs, 'Zero.png'), 'png')

    if labels[(x, y)]==1:
        One[y][x]=int(255)
        count1=count1+1
        if count1<=43:
            continue
        elif count1>43:
            First = Image.fromarray(One)
            First.save(os.path.join(dirs, 'First.png'),'png')
```

Comment: It is using two pass connected component algorithm for detecting components in image so uf is array file and, labels are on every coordinate x and coordinate y the value is called label so "==0" means one shape which is labeled as "0" and so on

Comment: did u get can u solve

Answer (score 1):

Since the `if` blocks follow the same logic, except for the source array (Zero, One, ...) and target filename (Zero.png, First.png, etc). You could record this information in a dictionary where keys are labels. For example:

```
dict = {
        0: {"source": Zero, "file": "Zero.png"},
        1: {"source": One, "file": "First.png"},    # and so on. 
       }
```

Then, in the loop, you just look up the label using `dict.get`:

```
data = dict.get(labels[(x, y)])
if data:     # data will be None (falsy) if label isn't in the dictionary   
    data["source"][y][x] = int(255)
    count += 1
    if count <= 43:
        continue
    elif count > 43:
        image = Image.fromarray(data["source"])
        image.save(os.path.join(dirs, data["file"]), 'png')
```